# Order a list of numbers without built-in sort, min, max function

Tags: python, sorting, for-loop

If I have a list that varies in length each time and I want to sort it from lowest to highest, how would I do that?

If I have: `[-5, -23, 5, 0, 23, -6, 23, 67]`

I want: `[-23, -6, -5, 0, 5, 23, 23, 67]`

I start with this:

```
data_list = [-5, -23, 5, 0, 23, -6, 23, 67]

new_list = []

minimum = data_list[0]  # arbitrary number in list 

for x in data_list: 
  if x < minimum:
    minimum = value
    new_list.append(i)
```

BUT this only goes through once and I get:

```
new_list = [-23]
```

This is where I get stuck.

How do I keep looping through until the `len(new_list) = len(data_list)` (i.e. all the numbers are in the new list) with everything sorted without using the built in max, min, sort functions?  I'm not sure if it's necessary to create a new list either.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I guess you are trying to do something like this:

```
data_list = [-5, -23, 5, 0, 23, -6, 23, 67]
new_list = []

while data_list:
    minimum = data_list[0]  # arbitrary number in list 
    for x in data_list: 
        if x < minimum:
            minimum = x
    new_list.append(minimum)
    data_list.remove(minimum)    

print (new_list)
```

#Added parenthesis

Answer (score 24):

```
l = [64, 25, 12, 22, 11, 1,2,44,3,122, 23, 34]

for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(l)):

        if l[i] > l[j]:
           l[i], l[j] = l[j], l[i]

print l
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 22, 23, 25, 34, 44, 64, 122]
```

Comment: The simplicity, brevity, and lack of built-in functions makes this a really elegant solution.

Answer (score 6):

This strictly follows your requirements not to use `sort()`, `min()`, `max()` but also uses Python best practice by not re-inventing the wheel.

```
data_list = [-5, -23, 5, 0, 23, -6, 23, 67]
import heapq
heapq.heapify(data_list)
new_list = []
while data_list:
    new_list.append(heapq.heappop(data_list)))
```

I suggest having a look in the Python library for `heapq.py` to see how it works. Heapsort is quite a fun sorting algorithm as it lets you 'sort' an infinite stream, i.e. you can quickly get at the currently smallest item but also efficiently add new items to the the data to be sorted.

Answer (score 5):

Here is something that i have been trying.(Insertion sort- not the best way to sort but does the work)

```
def sort(list):
    for index in range(1,len(list)):
        value = list[index]
        i = index-1
        while i>=0:
            if value < list[i]:
                list[i+1] = list[i]
                list[i] = value
                i -= 1
            else:
                break
```

Answer (score 3):

This works!

```
def sorting(li):
    for i in range(len(li)):
        for j in range(len(li)):
            if li[i] < li[j]:
                li[j],li[i] = li[i],li[j]
    return li

listToSort = [22,11,23,1,100,24,3,101,2,4]
print(sorting(listToSort))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# Your current setup
data_list = [-5, -23, 5, 0, 23, -6, 23, 67]
new_list  = []

# Sort function
for i in data_list:
    new_list = [ x for x in new_list if i > x ] + [i] + [ x for x in new_list if i <= x ]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Add explanation to your logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
def bubble_sort(seq):
    """Inefficiently sort the mutable sequence (list) in place.
       seq MUST BE A MUTABLE SEQUENCE.

       As with list.sort() and random.shuffle this does NOT return 
    """
    changed = True
    while changed:
        changed = False
        for i in xrange(len(seq) - 1):
            if seq[i] > seq[i+1]:
                seq[i], seq[i+1] = seq[i+1], seq[i]
                changed = True
    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
   """Sample usage and simple test suite"""

   from random import shuffle

   testset = range(100)
   testcase = testset[:] # make a copy
   shuffle(testcase)
   assert testcase != testset  # we've shuffled it
   bubble_sort(testcase)
   assert testcase == testset  # we've unshuffled it back into a copy
```

From :
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bubble_Sort#Python

Comment: it just randomizes the array ... so instead of shuffle and all that just pass in your list to tje bubble_sort function

Comment: `bubble_sort(data_list);print data_list`

Comment: oh well what are you supposed to use..? just selection??

Comment: good question. theoretically, I want to find the minimum first, append it to a new list and each # that is subsequently the next minimum (by iterating through a list or with a for-loop possibly).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [not very efficient](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/heinous) sorting algorithm :)

```
>>> data_list = [-5, -23, 5, 0, 23, -6, 23, 67]
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> for p in permutations(data_list):
...     if all(i<=j for i,j in zip(p,p[1:])):
...         print p
...         break
... 
(-23, -6, -5, 0, 5, 23, 23, 67)
```

Comment: thanks for this! i'm very new to python and intertools and permutations are also things i've found when searching google but i can't use those either.

Comment: That method is getting very close to a meme.  I like it!

Answer (score 1):

try sorting list , char have the ascii code, the same can be used for sorting the list of char.

```
aw=[1,2,2,1,1,3,5,342,345,56,2,35,436,6,576,54,76,47,658,8758,87,878]
for i in range(aw.__len__()):
    for j in range(aw.__len__()):
        if aw[i] < aw[j] :aw[i],aw[j]=aw[j],aw[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it easily by using min() function

```
`def asc(a):
    b=[]
    l=len(a)
    for i in range(l):
        x=min(a)
        b.append(x)
        a.remove(x)
    return b
 print asc([2,5,8,7,44,54,23])`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [3, 1, 5, 2, 4]
n = len(data)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(1,n):
            if data[j-1] > data[j]:
                (data[j-1], data[j]) = (data[j], data[j-1])
    print(data)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

Below code can be used to sort the list:

```
lst=[1, 5, 0, 0, 9, 10, 9, 3, 2, 3, 5,10]
sorted_list=[]

while lst:
    sorted_list.append((min(lst)))
    lst.remove(min(lst))

print("Sorted list: ", sorted_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

My method-

```
s = [-5, -23, 5, 0, 23, -6, 23, 67]
nl = []
for i in range(len(s)):
    a = min(s)
    nl.append(a)
    s.remove(a)

print nl
```

Comment: I presume the question's purpose was learning something about sorting algorithms. This code is very inefficient: `min(s)` would scan all the elements for `s`, and as well `s.remove`, assuming it's an array, would take O(n) to remove the element. This for every element in `s`. You end up with a quadratic sorting algorithm.

Comment: There's also the issue that the OP explicitly said (right in the title) order a list ... without ... min ... function

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
mylist = [1, 6, 7, 8, 1, 10, 15, 9]
print(mylist)
n = len(mylist)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(1, n-i):
        if mylist[j-1] > mylist[j]:
             (mylist[j-1], mylist[j]) = (mylist[j], mylist[j-1])
print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more readable example of an *in-place* [Insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) algorithm.

```
a = [3, 1, 5, 2, 4]

for i in a[1:]:
    j = a.index(i)
    while j > 0 and a[j-1] > a[j]:
        a[j], a[j-1] = a[j-1], a[j]
        j = j - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_sort(lst):
    a = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        a.append(min(lst))
        lst.remove(min(lst))
    return a

def my_revers_sort(lst):#in revers!!!!!
    a = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        a.append(max(lst))
        lst.remove(max(lst))
    return a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input("Input list lenght: "))
lista = []
for i in range (1,n+1):
    print ("A[",i,"]=")
    ele = int(input())
    lista.append(ele)
print("The list is: ",lista)
invers = True
while invers == True:
    invers = False 
    for i in range (n-1):
        if lista[i]>lista[i+1]:
            c=lista[i+1]
            lista[i+1]=lista[i]
            lista[i]=c
            invers = True
print("The sorted list is: ",lista)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swapping the values from 1st position to till the end of the list, this code loops for ( n*n-1)/2 times. Each time it pushes the greater value to the greater index starting from Zero index.

```
list2 = [40,-5,10,2,0,-4,-10]
for l in range(len(list2)):
    for k in range(l+1,len(list2)):
        if list2[k] < list2[l]:
            list2[k] , list2[l] = list2[l], list2[k]
print(list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since complexity doesn’t matter, I present to you...BogoSort:

```
from random import shuffle

def is_sorted(ls):
    for idx in range(len(ls)-1):
        if x[idx] > x[idx + 1]:
          return False
    return True

def sort(ls):
    while not is_sorted(ls):
        shuffle(ls)
    return ls


ls = list(range(5))
shuffle(ls)

print(
    "Original: ",
    ls
)

print(
    "Sorted: ",
    sorted(ls)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the unsorted list and we want is 1234567

```
list = [3,1,2,5,4,7,6]

def sort(list):
    for i in range(len(list)-1):
        if list[i] > list[i+1]:
            a = list[i]
            list[i] = list[i+1]
            list[i+1] = a
        print(list)       

sort(list)
```

simplest in simplest method to sort a array.
Im using currently bubble sorting that is: it checks first 2 location and moves the smallest number to left so on.
"-n"in loop is to avoid the indentation error you will understand it by doing it so.

Answer (score 0):

You can used iterative approach one by one comparing along with recursive function. The result in ascending order if you want descending order then change the condition from `if l[i]>l[i+1]` to `if l[i]<l[i+1]`:

```
l=[2,1,3,4,3,2,1,2] 
list_len=len(l)

def fun(l):
    for i in range(list_len):
        if i<list_len-1:
            if l[i]>l[i+1]:
                l[i],l[i+1]=l[i+1],l[i]
                fun(l)
    return l
            
print(fun(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range (0, len(unsorted_list)):
    for j in range (i,  len(unsorted_list)):
        if unsorted_list[i]> unsorted_list[j]:
            unsorted_list[i], unsorted_list[j] = unsorted_list[j], unsorted_list[i]

print("Sorted list: ", unsorted_list)
```

output is:
Sorted list:  [0, 5, 9, 10, 11, 20, 100, 100]

Time complexity is Quadratic time – O (n^2)

Answer (score 0):

**Use this with for loop**

```
    arr = [1, 5, 0, 0, 9, 10, 9, 3, 2, 3, 5,10]
    new_arr = []
    for index in range(len(arr)):
        index = len(new_arr) - index
        max_val = arr[index]
        for val in arr[index+1:]:
            if val >= max_val:
                max_val = val
        new_arr.append(max_val)
        arr.remove(max_val)
    print(new_arr)
```

**Use this with while loop**

```
    arr = [1, 5, 0, 0, 9, 10, 9, 3, 2, 3, 5,10]
    new_arr = []
    while arr:
        max_val = arr[0]
        for x in arr:
            if x >= max_val:
                max_val = x
        new_arr.append(max_val)
        arr.remove(max_val)
    
    print(new_arr)
```

**With function,for ASC use reverse = 1 and -1 for DESC**

````
    def custom_sorting(numbers, new_list, reverse=-1):
        for i in range(len(numbers)):
            first_num = numbers[0]
            for num in numbers:
                if num < first_num and reverse < 0:
                    first_num = num
                if num > first_num and reverse > 0:
                    first_num = num
    
            numbers.remove(first_num)
            new_list.append(first_num)
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        data = [5, 4, 2, 8, 70, 0, 0, 96, 5]
        newlist = []
        custom_sorting(data, newlist, reverse=1)
        print(newlist)```
````

Answer (score -1):

> How do I keep looping through until the len(new_list) = len(data_list)

```
while len(new_list) != len(data_list):
    # ...
```

Maybe like this?

And no, it’s not necessary to create a new list; most sorting algorithms work by changing the list in place.

What you probably trying to do is [Selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) with a separate list. See the Wikipedia article for more information about that sorting algorithm and you’ll see how it works with a single list, and how efficient it is (spoiler: it isn’t).

Comment: Actually, the original code won't do anything close to the selection sort. It does not find the minimum value in the list, it finds the first value in the list which is less than the value of the `minimum` variable.

Comment: Oh this is helpful. But here's my follow-up question - how do I go through the list again so it doesn't give me the same minimum? I probably have to remove it from data_list?

Comment: You have to remember which you already sorted, which is also something you get from changing the list. By remembering that everything before index `i` is already sorted, you only need to look at those elements above that.

Comment: @penartur I was obviously reading more than there was ;) Changed my answer to reflect that belief.

Answer (score -1):

we can sort a list by keeping it inside set,as set gives output as unique numbers that too in ascending order.

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] the post to clarify what you mean here.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

```
def getIndexOfMaximum(list1):
    index = 0
    emptyList = []
    value = list1[0]
    c = 0
    while (c == 0):
        for cell in list1:
            index += 1
            if (cell >= value):
                value = cell
                hold = index -1
            if (len(list1) == index):
                emptyList += [value]
                del list1[hold]
                index = 0
                value = 0
                if (len(list1) == 1):
                    newList = emptyList + list1
                    del list1[index]
                    c = 1
    return newList
print(getIndexOfMaximum([2,5,8,7,44,54,23]))

#TRY THIS!!!
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your answer to include more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".