# Finding the Minimum and Maximum of a list of values without sorting or using any built in Functions or Libraries

Tags: python, function, max, min, minimum

I need to find the minimum value of a list of values but I am prohibited from using any built in function or libraries. I am allowed to use if else or elif but that is the extent.

I have to use basic operators and (I suppose?) my own intuition to figure this out.

Unfortunately I am not that intuitive and no matter what combination of if else statements I use or < > operators, I just cannot get it to work.

I'm really new to python and my teacher did little to help describe how to even go about doing this (other than defining operators. That's literally all he did).

So basically I have a list of three integers and I have to find the min and max of those three integers (gotta find some other stuff too but let's keep this simple). I have to use functions to define the integers and separate functions to define the min and max of the list.

I have the function for defining the integers, that was easy, now I'm stuck on this:

```
def determine_min_value(a,b,c):
    print ("The minimum value is {}.".format(c < (b < a)))
```

with a, b, and c being variables (num1, num2, num3)

it outputs "The minimum value is False." which would be great if False was a really small number, and also one of the input variables; which it obviously is not.

I'm fully aware that .format(c < (b < a)) is not going to give me what I want, but that was my latest last ditch effort. Like I said I was trying if else statements, but I couldn't figure those out either.

I simply have no idea where to go from here and any input would be greatly appreciated. Also I know you want to say "Just put them in a list and use min(1)" but again, I am not allowed. I would love nothing more than to do that as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964450/python-order-a-list-of-numbers-without-built-in-sort-min-max-function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: order a list of numbers without built-in sort, min, max function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964450/python-order-a-list-of-numbers-without-built-in-sort-min-max-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Since you cannot use reduce(), you can do it inline for three integers as follows:

```
maximum = lambda x, y, z: x if x > (y and z) else y if y > z else z
maximum(1, 5, 7)
```

If you really want to avoid lambda for the sake of a professor then you could write it traditionally:

```
def maximum (x, y, z):
    if x > y and z:
        return x
    elif y > z:
        return y
    else:
        return z
```

To expand the above functionality when the input scales very large would best be implemented the use of a built in function called reduce (especially if you are trying to do something other than check max or min which is obviously a built-in functionality).

```
from functools import reduce

def check_greater(a,b):
    if a > b:
        return b
    else:
        return a

number_list = [1,6,3,8,5,78,4,23,9]

minimum = reduce(check_greater, number_list)
```

This will apply the check_greater() function to every pair of elements in the list and will continually return one value for every pair, corresponding to which is lower.

First 1 and 6 will be compared.  Since 1 is lower, it will be returned in place of both of those values.  Now 1 and 3 will be compared.  Again, since it is lower it will be returned to replace both of those values.  Perhaps I should have nested 1 somewhere in the middle to make it more obvious but no matter where the minimum value falls in the list of numbers, the reduce function will take your entire iterable and return a single value based upon the function you pass as the first argument.

Note that you can do the same with a maximum, just switch a and b in the return statements of the check_greater() function.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not allowed to use built in libraries or functions and functools as well as the reduce function violate both of those restrictions. I appreciate you taking the time to help me figure this out though. 

I also want to thank you for making this functionality known to me as I wouldn't have even thought of it even if I could use functions.

Comment: The answer at the top is probably the fewest lines of code you can use. The second function reduces a few lines off of gil.fernandes solution. If you need to do something complex to an iterable it's good to use reduce, so I left that there

Comment: @Reti43 you're right, I should have used "and" instead of chaining the operators. I've made a fix now, thanks!

Comment: I didn't even see your edit until after I figured it out. Either way amazing description, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention *a list of values*, you could do it by recursion

```
import numpy as np

def mymin(lst):
    if not lst:
        return np.inf 
    head = lst[0]
    tail = mymin(lst[1:])
    return head if head < tail else tail
```

What it does

- the min of the list is either the first element, or the min of the rest
- the empty list is ignored (by having an infinite value)

However, keep in mind that it is not efficient in python

Comment: I think the idea is not for it to be efficient, but more for it to be a pain in the ass.

Comment: @TristanStroud: OK, this example is!

Comment: This uses a library, which is against the OP's requirements.

Comment: @Reti43: I don't think this goes against the rules, as the point of the exercise is obviously to think of a way to implement `min`.

Comment: Then we have a different understanding of the rules, because the OP states in the first line "I am prohibited from using any built in function or libraries". It's a pedantic exercise and while you don't use numpy in any direct way to compute the min/max, but it's up to the teacher how to interpret the rules.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on for a while and ended up with

```
    # function determines and defines the minimum value
def det_min_value(a,b,c):
    print ("The minimum value is {}.".format(a if (a < b and c)
                                                 else b if (b < c and a)
                                                     else c))
    # for range function 
    return (a if (a < b and c)
                else b if (b < c and a)
                    else c)
```

Works really well. Without the information provided for me here I wouldn't have been able to do it so thank you all very much!