# How can i sort in python without using sort function

Tags: python, sorting, bubble-sort

I am trying to sort a list in ascending order but there some problems. How can I fix them exactly.

Code shown below. Please assist me.

```
def Sorting_a_List(input_list):
  My_List=[]
  b=[]
  for k in range(0,len(input_list)):
    for a in range(0,len(input_list)-1):
        if input_list[k]<input_list[a+1]:
            a=a+1
        else:
            b=input_list[k]
            input_list[k]=input_list[a+1]
            input_list[a+1]=b
  return input_list
```

Comment: What's your motivation for not using `sort`?

Comment: The indentation is invalid. Is that the problem you're asking about?

Comment: i mean when i put input as [3,8,2,7] then output will be [2,8,3,7]

Comment: im trying to handle without sort function (because in edx platform given like that question)

Comment: actually code pasted incorretly i realised now. We can no indentation problem. Just code function not correct

Comment: @yusuf Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11964572/6225617

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code. I did as less changes as I could, so that it is easier for you to understand. Just copy-save-run this code as it is:

```
def Sorting_a_List(input_list):
    for k in range(0,len(input_list)):
        for a in range(0,len(input_list)-1):
            if input_list[k]>input_list[a]:
                continue
            else:
                b=input_list[k]
                input_list[k]=input_list[a]
                input_list[a]=b
    return input_list

# If you just need the function, then skip copying the lines below!
input_list = input("Enter the list separated by space: ").split()
input_list = list(map(int,input_list))
print("Your list in Ascending order:",Sorting_a_List(input_list))
```

The code above (based on your code) seems quite busy, so below is just a clearer version using Bubble sort:

```
def bubble_sort(inputList):
    index = len(inputList) - 1
    while index >= 0:
        for j in range(index):
            if inputList[j] > inputList[j+1]:
                inputList[j], inputList[j+1] = inputList[j+1], inputList[j]
        index -= 1
    return inputList

# If you just need the function, then skip copying the lines below!
inputList = input("Enter the list separated by space: ").split()
inputList = list(map(int,inputList))
print("Your list in Ascending order:",bubble_sort(inputList))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you  much for concern.

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept it as the best answer and also upvote it, if it has helped you!

Comment: yes its helped. After then also i can write like that code.