# Sort list in ascending order with odd and even in python

Tags: python

I have a list `listOfNumbers = [3,2,1,4,5,6,7,8,9,22,25,16,17,28]` I want to sort this list in ascending order but first of all odd number then even number like this :

```
[1, 5, 7, 9, 11, 15, 19, 29,'startOF->evens', 4, 8, 10, 14, 16, 28, 32, 66]
```

without sort function

I've tried this but I get an error

```
data_list = [3,2,1,4,5,6,7,8,9,22,25,16,17,28]
new_list = []
while data_list:
    minimum = data_list[0]
    for x in data_list: 
        if x < minimum:
            minimum = x
    new_list.append(minimum)
    data_list.remove(minimum)
    print (new_list)
def Huhu(data_list):
  ev_li = ''
    od_li = ''
    for i in data_list: 
        if (i % 2 == 0): 
            ev_li.append(i) 
        else: 
            od_li.append(i)
    print(new_list,od_li "startOF->evens",ev_li)
```

Thanks for the response I've done

```
data_list = [3,2,1,4,5,6,7,8,9,22,25,16,17,28]
new_list = []

while data_list:
    minimum = data_list[0]  # arbitrary number in list 
    for x in data_list: 
        if x < minimum:
            minimum = x
    new_list.append(minimum)
    data_list.remove(minimum)
odds = []
evens = []
for i in new_list:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        evens.append(i)
    else:
        odds.append(i)
print(odds,"startOF->evens", evens)
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you tell us which error you're getting.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sorted` with a custom `key` argument to sort by.

```
>>> sorted(listOfNumbers, key=lambda i: (i%2==0, i))
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 17, 25, 2, 4, 6, 8, 16, 22, 28]
```

In this case you can first sort by odd/even, then by the value itself.

Comment: I need without "sort" function

Comment: If you have to write your own sort function there are [questions that cover that already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964450/python-order-a-list-of-numbers-without-built-in-sort-min-max-function), all you have to do is specify what specifically to sort by. [Wikipedia has an entire page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) on various sorting algorithms you can implement.

Comment: I know this method but I need also list where I can put even and odd in ascending order

Comment: The algorithms are generic. They can be applied to any set of values. Just use a sorting algorithm and modify it to prefer odds first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know why you code fails:

```
data_list = [3,2,1,4,5,6,7,8,9,22,25,16,17,28]
new_list = []
while data_list:
    minimum = data_list[0]
    for x in data_list: 
        if x < minimum:
            minimum = x
    new_list.append(minimum)
    data_list.remove(minimum)
    print (new_list)
def Huhu(data_list):
    ev_li = list()
    od_li = list()
    for i in data_list: 
        if (i % 2 == 0): 
            ev_li.append(i) 
        else: 
            od_li.append(i)
    print(new_list,od_li, "startOF->evens",ev_li)
```

You have three errors:

First: indentation problem:

```
def Huhu(data_list):
  ev_li = ''
    od_li = '' <- Here
```

Second: a comma is missed here:

```
print(new_list,od_li [here] "startOF->evens",ev_li)
```

Third:

ev_li and od_li must be `list`

But for sure @CoryKramer is cleaner :P